# Django: Using template.render() and l10n

Tags: django

I have a piece of code that sends an e-mail with attached CSV file. The CSV contains pricing information. My country uses a comma as decimal separator, so I want prices to be converted in the CSV data. However, this is not working as intended.

The code uses a template which is also being used in another part of the app to generate these CSVs. In this case, conversion works as intended.

My l10n & i18n config looks like this:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nl-NL'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Amsterdam'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

The code responsible for parsing the template manually:

```
template = get_template("template_file.html")
context = Context({'object_list': get_object_list()}, use_l10n=True)
csv = template.render(context)
```

Part of the template:

```
Aantal;Eenheid;Product;Omschrijving;Inkoopprijs Euro
{%  for product in object_list %}"{{ product.amount_sum }}";"{{ product.unit_of_measurement }}";"{{ product.name }}";"{{ product.description }}";"{{ product.base_price }}"
{% endfor %}
```

(`base_price` is a `DecimalField`)

Comment: Have you activated Dutch as the active language in your script? Otherwise I believe it will default to `None`, which means: don't translate anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should propably use `RequestContext` here:

```
context = RequestContext(request, {'object_list': get_object_list()}, use_l10n=True)
```

Without that django template engine won't know which locale is being used.

Comment: The thing is, there is no originating ```request``` because this is a periodic task.